# NoClassDefFound Exception Solution

Tags: android

When I run my app on android version 6 and above it run perfect but on version **<6** it gives an error

```
 "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
 Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;".
```

I have one app on two different paths when I run from the first path it gives an error mentioned above but from another path, it runs perfectly. 
why can anyone give me a solution?

this is my gradle

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file ?

Comment: no i don't post gridle

Comment: @RohitSingh so you want people to help you but you don't want to provide any information that helps them?

Comment: you take another mine of my words i provide my gradle file ok

Comment: Edit your first post, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [the documentation of VectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat), This class was added on the API 24. Which, according to the [correspondence table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels), is Android 7.0.

So it's the expected behaviour that the class is not found on Android below 6.0